# JavaScript function to convert unicode pseduo-alphabet to regular characters?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I am trying to write a function that takes any string containing characters in the unicode pseduo-alphabets and returns an equivalent string where such characters have been replaced with the regular characters found in ASCII.

```js
const toRegularCharacters = s => {
  // ?
};

toRegularCharacters('ⓗⓔⓛⓛⓞ, ⓦⓞⓡⓛⓓ'); // "hello, world"
toRegularCharacters(', '); // "hello, world"
toRegularCharacters('ん乇ﾚﾚo, wo尺ﾚd'); // "hello, world"
```

I don't want to write a look-up table myself. I have looked at various "slugify" libraries, but they only remove accents etc. Ideally the function should work in Node and the browser.

Of course, not every special character will have a regular equivalent. The solution should make a reasonable guess in these cases (e.g. `"尺" -> "R"`). It should work flawlessly for the pseudo-alphabets with "true transforms":

> Current true transforms:
>   circled, negative circled, Asian fullwidth, math bold, math bold Fraktur, math bold italic, math bold script, math double-struck, math monospace, math sans, math sans-serif bold, math sans-serif bold italic, math sans-serif italic, parenthesized, regional indicator symbols, squared, negative squared, and tagging text (invisible for hidden metadata tagging).

- From https://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi

How should I go about this?

---

Going from a "regular" string to a pseudo-alphabet one is implemented here: https://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=hello%2C+world

Comment: Since ん, 乇, 尺 and ﾚ are nowhere near any western letters, there's no other way than to use custom lookup tables. For the other letters it may be possible in some form or another, but not for those.

Comment: @deceze I see your point; the implementation does not have to be perfect.

Comment: Well, what letters are you targeting? Just the small number shown here as samples? Or *anything that even remotely looks like anything else*…?

Comment: @deceze - Unicode has the concept of "confusables," which are included in the database. For instance: the  from ,  is [U+1D4F1](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1D4F1), which lists the standard latin lower case `h` ([U+0068](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0068)) as a confusable.

Comment: @T.J. Fair enough, that doesn't get you to ん though. This is really a pretty arbitrary question as is.

Comment: @T.J. ん is not a confusable of anything…!? https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=3093&B1=Show

Comment: @T.J. Go ahead and post your answer then… But since the input is based on an entirely arbitrary mapping, and OP doesn't want to create a custom mapping, IMO there's no _real_ solution to this…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59614218/1256041), this solution uses the `unicode-12.1.0` NPM package:

```js
const unicodeNames = require('unicode-12.1.0/Names');

const overrides = Object.freeze({
  'ん': 'h',
  '乇': 'E',
  'ﾚ': 'l',
  '尺': 'r',
  // ...
});

const toRegularCharacters = xs => {
  if (typeof xs !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError('xs must be a string');
  }

  return [ ...xs ].map(x => {
    const override = overrides[x];

    if (override) {
      return override;
    }

    const names = unicodeNames
      .get(x.codePointAt(0))
      .split(/\s+/);

    // console.log({
    //   x,
    //   names,
    // });

    const isCapital = names.some(x => x == 'CAPITAL');

    const isLetter = isCapital || names.some(x => x == 'SMALL');

    if (isLetter) {
      // e.g. "Ŧ" is named "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T WITH STROKE"
      const c = names.some(x => x == 'WITH') ?
        names[names.length - 3] :
        names[names.length - 1];

      return isCapital ?
        c :
        c.toLowerCase();
    }

    return x;
  }).join('');
};

console.log(
  toRegularCharacters('..')
);

console.log(
  toRegularCharacters('-')
);

console.log(
  toRegularCharacters('ん乇ﾚﾚo, wo尺ﾚd')
);

console.log(
  toRegularCharacters('ŦɆSŦƗNǤ')
);
```

The `Names` data-table contains the required information, but not in the best form, so there is some hacky string manipulation to get the character out.

A map of overrides is used for cases such as `'尺'`.

A better solution would extract the `idn_mapping` property as mentioned by @Seth.

Answer (score 3):

You could write your code to query the Unicode database, which you can download from the [Unicode consortium](https://unicode.org/) (or query via the [character utility](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp), but that's presumably rate-limited). The database includes things like what glyphs are "confusables" for other glyphs.

For instance, your  from ,  is [U+1D4F1](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1D4F1), which has **lots** of confusables, one of which is of course the standard latin lower case h ([U+0068](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0068)). So you could go through each char in the input string, look it up, and if it had a latin a-z confusable (perhaps 0-9 as well), replace it with that.

It won't be perfect. As deceze pointed out, [ん](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=3093) doesn't list any confusables, even if it does look vaguely like an "h" to an English reader. Neither does [ⓗ](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=24D7). So you may need to supplement with your own lookup even though you've said you don't want to (or just live with the imperfection).

Comment: The `idn_mapping` in the character utility result looks promising too - https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=%F0%9D%93%B1&B1=Show

Comment: @Seth - Ooooh, yeah.